# Why does this Ruby code attempting an HTTP API call hang the process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I am trying to call an api (from controller), store its resulting JSON response in a variable and then access parts of the variable's value at will (in my view). The following code hangs:

*in Controller:*

```
parsed_response = JSON.parse(HTTP.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/storefront/products'))
@products = parsed_response['data']
```

*in View:*

```
<%= @products %>
```

The above renders nothing, hangs up a process and I have to `kill -9` to shut down the server. What am I doing wrong here, is this somehow making the `HTTP.get` request more than once in rapid succession, thus causing the process to hang? Is it to do with the #parse and #get both being called at once on one line?

(I'm using gem 'http' here)

Comment: If I load that URL in my browser it renders the JSON response packet just fine.

Comment: What is your web server? Puma?

Comment: Yes, my webserver is Puma (I'm running this in development mode on my local machine).

Comment: My guess then is that it is `Rack::Lock` to "blame". Try setting `config.allow_concurrency=true` in development environment (or `config.threadsafe!`) - it might help. But honestly I'd reconsider the solution - http requests to own endpoints is an incredible waste of resources...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your server (puma, unicorn, ..) accepts a limited number of parallel HTTP connections.

Suppose your app accepts only one connection at a time:

- Your request `localhost:3000/page_1`, so you occupy that connection. No one can connect to your server until this connection is over.
- `localhost:3000/page_1` wants to connect to `localhost:3000/page_2`, it has to wait until the active connection ends. Since it cannot connect, it waits... until a timeout or until you kill your server.

Comment: I think it must be something to do with my code, I've since found that this works;

`response = (HTTP.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v2/storefront/products'))
    parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
    @products = parsed_response['data']`

And as this does work with both the browser rendering @products and the API call happening just before from the controller then that determines that my server can accept parallel http connections, doesn't it?

Perhaps it's the method chaining in the 1st original line? But if so why?